# Adding labels to a table

Tags: tables

[image]

In the following post I have submitted a picture of my current table and what I am trying to make. I am having trouble adding the row with the labels symbol, description, units and estimated like I have shown in my desired table drawing

[image: tablewanted]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Parameter} & a & surface area of the hole & cm\textsuperscript{2} & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
& A & cross-sectional area of the hole & cm\textsuperscript{2} & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
& u & velocity of water leaving the hole & cm/s & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
& g & gravitational constant & cm/s\textsuperscript{2} & 0 \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{Initial Conditions} & V(0) & initial volume of water above the hole & cm & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{Variables} & V(t) & volume of water at time t & mL & 0 \\
\cline{2-5}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the edit! would you be able to help me with my problem?

Comment: welcome to tex. se! i took a liberty and replace your screenshot with image of table generated with your mwe. however, i don't understand well, what is your problem.

Comment: at list provide bigger sketch. from it i don't see what is difference between generated and hand drawn table.

Comment: above a, surface area, cm^2, 0 there are the labels symbol, description, units, estimated respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & Symbol & Description & Units & Estimated\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Parameter} & a & surface area of the hole & cm\textsuperscript{2} & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
& A & cross-sectional area of the hole & cm\textsuperscript{2} & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
& u & velocity of water leaving the hole & cm/s & 0\\
\cline{2-5}
& g & gravitational constant & cm/s\textsuperscript{2} & 0 \\
\hline
Initial Conditions & V(0) & initial volume of water above the hole & cm & 0\\
\hline
Variables & V(t) & volume of water at time t & mL & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

i would design your table as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l>{$}c<{$}llc}
    & \text{Symbol}
            & \hfil Description                   & Units     & Estimated\\
    \midrule
Parameters
    & a     & surface area of the hole                  & \si{m^2}  & 0 \\
    & A     & cross-sectional area of the hole          & \si{m^2}  & 0 \\
    & u     & velocity of water leaving the hole        & \si{cm/s} & 0 \\
    & g     & gravitational constant                    & \si{cm/s} & 0 \\
    \midrule
Initial Conditions
    & V(0)  & initial volume of water above the hole    & \si{cm}   & 0 \\
Variables
    & V(t) & volume of water at time $t$                & \si{mL}   & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to put a line inbetween initial conditions and variables like you have a line between Parameters and initial conditions?

Comment: @user123: For an additional horizontal line between Initial Conditions and Variables, add the command `\midrule` between  \\ and Variables.

Comment: of course, just add `\midrule` where you like to have (before "variables")

Comment: I would prefer header like   "& \text{Symbol}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\hspace{30pt} Description   \hfill      Units\hspace{4pt} }& Estimated\\" ... +1 by the way

Answer (score 0):

I would use `siunitx` for the fourth column, and the `cellspace` package for some vertical padding of the rows. NOte that only one  `multirow` command id required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{Cc|}}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}[-1.6ex]{Parameter}& a & %
{surface area of the hole} & \si{cm²} & 0 \\
\cline{2-5}
& A & %
{cross-sectional area of the hole} & \si {\cm²} & 0 \\
\cline{2-5}
 & u & {velocity of water leaving the hole} & \si{\cm\per \s} & 0 \\
\cline{2-5}
 & g & %
{gravitational constant} & \si{\cm\per \s\squared} & 0 \\
\hline
Initial Conditions & V(0) & initial volume of water above the hole & \si{cm }& 0 \\
\cline{2-5}
\hline
Variables & V(t) & volume of water at time t &\si{mL} & 0 \\
\cline{2-5}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]